# How to return invoice numbers - where all associated detail records have a bit field set to 1

Tags: sql-server-2008

SQL novice here.

I'm trying to get a list of invoice numbers. There are two tables - invoices and invoicedetail. The invoicedetail table has a field called scanned (it's a bit field). If it's been scanned, then the bit field is 1.

For each invoice, there are associated records in the invoicedetail, but I only want a list of the invoice numbers where every associated record in invoicedetail's scanned field is 1.

I'd rather do this in a single query if possible.

The records scanned in InvoiceDetail is all records  - for any invoice number returned.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   InvoiceNumber 
FROM 
   Invoice 
INNER JOIN 
   InvoiceDetail 
ON 
   InvoiceDetail.ID = Invoice.ID 
WHERE 
   InvoiceDetail.ScannedColumn=1 
GROUP BY 
   Invoice.InvoiceNumber
```

Or...

```
SELECT
   DISTINCT
   InvoiceNumber
FROM
   Invoice it
INNER JOIN
   InvoiceDetail idt 
ON idt.ID = it.ID
WHERE
  idt.ScannedColumn=1
```

Just make sure you change the column names to fit your needs.  Use your ID from each table for the joins and  then use a `WHERE` to filter the records to just show those which are scanned.  Being that you are using a bit field you will simply use `WHERE ScannedColumn = 1`.

Comment: If you want more than just the InvoiceNumber the group by solution is becoming a pain quite soon.
    SELECT *
    FROM Invoice
    WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT Id FROM InvoiceDetail WHERE Scanned = 1)
This solution however may suffer from performance issues when things are getting bigggg

Comment: @Paul - that is not up to me or you, the OP has asked for just the invoice number.  As a good practice, you should never use `SELECT *...` even if you need ALL the columns, you should explicitly mark each column you want.

Comment: you're right just the number that's what he asked for. However I like to brace for impact, that is prob. the handicap I've developed over the years programming customer-specified software.

Comment: "SELECT [Invoices].[InvoiceID]  
FROM Invoices it 
INNER JOIN InvoiceDetail idt ON idt.InvoiceID = it.InvoiceID 
WHERE idt.Scanned = 1 ORDER BY it.Invoiceid DESC" - this is field specific according to my table schema, however I get an error I don't understand. It is "The multi-part identifier "Invoices.InvoiceID" could not be bound. I tried explicitly identifying the InvoiceID from Invoices, but that was all I could think of and didn't help. What would correct this?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT [Invoices].[InvoiceID]  
FROM Invoices INNER JOIN InvoiceDetail ON InvoiceDetail.InvoiceID = Invoices.InvoiceID  
WHERE InvoiceDetail.Scanned = 1 
ORDER BY Invoices.Invoiceid DESC works, so it looks like I just needed to remove the aliases and format it correctly - I can't seem to format the comment - sorry. But you did answer my question, so thank you very much. - Cliff